# Ошибка SQLite3 Python: Can't parse entities: unsupported start tag "sqlite3.cursor" at byte offset 355

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Хочу выполнить этот код:

```
def count_refs(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE parent_id = ?',
                                   (user_id,))
```

Получаю эту ошибку: Can't parse entities: unsupported start tag "sqlite3.cursor" at byte offset 355

Искал информацию в Гугле, ничего не нашел. Он мне сам сказал что ничего я не найду: [image: вот]

В чем может быть связана проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте `with self.connection as con: con.cursor.execute()`

Comment: @Lecron Спасибо, помогло избавится от ошибки, и получить новую: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'

Comment: execute ленивый метод, поэтому у вас реальный доступ к данных происходит вне области видимости контекстного менеджера. Получайте сразу данные `.fetchall()`